# На каком языке писать на unity?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d

Сам я frontend-разработчик,со знанием javascript на достаточно высоком уровне,и продолжаю его учить. Но очень хочется поделать что-нибудь на unity,возможно заняться этим вплотную. Стоит для этого паррарельно учить c# или кодить на js? (стыдно)

Comment: Знания js там не особо помогут, так как у них свой фреймверк, кроме синтаксиса, ничего знакомого не видите. Я для себя сделал вывод что выучить c# будет значительно практичнее, но к сожалению пока не достаточно времени.

Comment: От js в unity не так много практической пользы. C# будет куда полезнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит от ваших потребностей. Пока работаете сами, хобби ради, или в небольшой команде (хотя и в ней можно договорится о языке скриптов) js должно хватать. Большинство примеров официальной документации дублируется на обоих js и с#, проблем с изучением быть не должно. 
Если вас интересует именно unity, учить нет смысла, потеряете много времени по итогу нормально ни то ни то не освоите.

Answer (score 0):

Редактор Unity имеет простой Drag&Drop интерфейс, который легко настраивать, состоящий из различных окон, благодаря чему можно производить отладку игры прямо в редакторе. Движок поддерживает два скриптовых языка: C#, JavaScript (модификация).
По мне то , JS гибкий и удобный язык , но если вы хотите писать на unity , лучше изучить C#